# Https code: Where is the html file served?

Tags: express

Sorry for a Noobish question. The following code works well to serve https files, and I'm happy to say serves the `Index.html` file fine with no problems, but I'm new to Express, and I don't see where/how in the code `Index.js` the server knows to serve the `Index.html` file.

Here's the code:

SERVER (`Index.js`)

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const directoryToServe = 'client';
const port = 3443;

app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'..',directoryToServe)));

const httpsOptions = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl', 'server.crt')),
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl','server.key'))
}

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app)
    .listen(port, function(){
        console.log(`Serving the ${directoryToServe}`);
    })
```

CLIENT (Directory where the `Index.html` file that's served to the client browser resides) `Index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>HTTPS App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTPS App</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Directory structure:

```
https-app
    client
        Index.html
    server
        Index.js
        ssl
            [ca, ca.key, ca.srl, etc., i.e., all the Certificates]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "https-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

I'm confused because there's no mention of `Index.html` in the code at all. To test, I added another file to the client folder (`Index2.html`), but the code ignores that file. Am I to assume that Express automatically looks for a file called `Index.html` in the `Static` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this line:

```
app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'..',directoryToServe)));
```

You are in `server` folder, then goes one step back and get in to `client` folder. By default the file to be serve is `index.html`

Answer (score 1):

You are telling the path where to look the `Index.html` file in this line. If your file name wasn't `index` then you had to tell the file name along with the path,

```
app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'..',directoryToServe)));
```